# "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when trying to find even numbers

Tags: python, string, runtime-error

I am getting this error on Python 3, `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. I know this is due to the string starting with `"["` but the problem I'm solving has this as the input string `'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'` and the task is to find the even numbers on Python 3. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def is_even_num(l):
  enum = []
  for n in l:
     if n % 2 == 0:
       enum.append(n)
  return enum
print(is_even_num('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'))
```

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

If I try `int(n)`, I get this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

#### Edit 1:

A similar problem I am facing due to the input being a STRING

Python Exercise: Sort a tuple by its float element

```
price = "[('item1', '12.20'), ('item2', '15.10'), ('item3', '24.5')]" 
print( sorted(price, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True))
```

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here 'Price' is a string and the problem is to Sort a tuple by its float element

2. Program to transpose a matrix using a nested loop

   ```
   y = "[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]"
   result = [[0,0],
     [0,0],
     [0,0],
     [0,0]]

   #iterate through rows
   for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns
       for j in range(len(X[0])):
           result[j][i] = X[i][j]
   for r in result:
       print(r)
   ```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am getting this same type of problem again, the matrix has been input as a STRING.

Comment: Because you’re passing it a string ... not a list ... your function as it stands needs a list of numbers, not a string that is the printed representation of a list ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[` and `]` and split the string:

```
def is_even_num(l):
  enum = []
  for n in l.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(', '):
    if int(n) % 2 == 0:
       enum.append(n)
  return enum
print(is_even_num('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'))
```

Output:

```
['2', '4', '6', '8']
```

Another ellegant way is to use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
def is_even_num(l):
  enum = []
  for n in ast.literal_eval(l):
    if int(n) % 2 == 0:
       enum.append(n)
  return enum
print(is_even_num('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'))
```

Output:

```
['2', '4', '6', '8']
```

Also for you second part of your question as said before just use `ast`:

```
price = "[('item1', '12.20'), ('item2', '15.10'), ('item3', '24.5')]"  
price = ast.literal_eval(price) 
print( sorted(price, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[('item3', '24.5'), ('item2', '15.10'), ('item1', '12.20')]
```

Then:

```
y = "[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]"
result = [[0,0],
 [0,0],
 [0,0],
 [0,0]]
X = ast.literal_eval(y)
#iterate through rows
for i in range(len(X)):
# iterate through columns
    for j in range(len(X[0])):
        result[j][i] = X[i][j]
for r in result:
  print(r)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4]
[2, 5]
[3, 6]
[4, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again @Codepope 
I have updated my question with 2 other problems I'm facing due to strings being passed as input! The input cannot be changed and they have to be supplied to the code as strings

Answer (score 0):

You pass your arguments as strings:

```
print(is_even_num('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'))
```

Change that to:

```
print(is_even_num([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I can't do that, the input has to be like this '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a list to your function, but a **string**. So the enumeration in your loop is going to enumerate the characters of your list, i.e. `'['` then `'1'`, then `','` etc.

That's probably not what you want.

Use that call instead:

```
print(is_even_num([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Comment: But the question has the string as input, cannot change that! I'm actually taking the input from the user!

Comment: You have to turn that into a list of integers. Use can use eval() which is unsafe, or you can parse that string. Use string methods such as strip() to remove unwanted spaces, check that the first and last chars are '[' and ']' and remove them, use the split method to split along commas, and convert the substrings to ints. Should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use "%" operator with Strings. Remove those char from your string that can not be converted to int or float.

```
def is_even_num(l):
    l = l.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(",")
    return [x for x in l if int(x)%2 ==0]
print(is_even_num('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'))
```

This will return a list of even numbers.